# Compilation errors for C++17 <filesystem> on MinGW

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

I want to play around with the new `filesystem` library that's now apart of the C++17 standard, however I can't get things to compile.

Things I've already tried:

- Updating MinGW to 8.2.0
- Compiling with `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test`
- Adding `-lstdc++fs` to the compilation (this does not work, I get the error `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++fs`)
- Using `<filesystem>` as well as `<experimental\filesystem>`

Here is my simple test code just to try and get things compiling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  return 0;
}
```

and compiling with `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test`

With this I get the error(s):

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\filesystem:37,
                 from test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h: In member function 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path& std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::operator/=(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
```

... many more errors ...

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h:603:7: note: suggested alternative: 'string_view'
       string_type __tmp;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
       string_view
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h:604:45: error: '__tmp' was not declared in this scope
       if (__str_codecvt_in(__first, __last, __tmp, __cvt))
```

Does anyone else have any suggestions? It seems like most people are solving this by adding `-lstdc++fs` to compilation, but like I said that doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to add`-lstdc++fs` to the compile command

Comment: OP says he already tried that, @Galik.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `<filesystem>` just doesn't work with MinGW as of right now...

Comment: Can you provide the commend you used *including* `-lstdc++fs`? The position of library flags is important

Comment: @Fureeish I was starting to wonder that. I thought their documentation said it did, but I must be wrong. Do you know what I should be using instead?

Comment: @Galik Oh I didn't realize order mattered! Unfortunately, I just tried every combo (`g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -lstdc++fs` and `g++ -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs test.cpp` and `g++ -lstdc++fs -std=c++17 test.cpp`) with no success.

Comment: Library flags should go at the end. :) But that may not be your problem it seems

Comment: @SamMcC, unfortunately I was unable to find a solution myself. I suppose you just need to use different compiler here :<

Comment: @Galik: No number of `-l` flags is going to fix overload resolution!

Answer (score 11):

The issue is with the mingw and gcc/g++ 8 branch itself, not with the compiler flags or pre-processor directives. The bug is open [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/737/).

Try using stable `mingw-w64-7.x` releases with `#include <experimental/filesystem>` directive and `-lstdc++fs -std=c++17` flags. This will work for now, or otherwise wait for v9.1.0.

On `experimental` channel you need to use `std::experimental::filesystem` instead of `std::filesystem`.

---

If you don't want to go with experimental features, switch to [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/). It has v10.2.0-6 of [gcc](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc) available as of Jan 2021.

Comment: thanks so much. i only found filesystem problem threads from like 2017 and thought this must be resolved in 2021. Could get it to compile with mingw 7 and experimental.