# just including - #include <filesystem> throws weird errors c++

Tags: c++

Both have c++17 std enabled. Whereas inclusion of `<filesystem>` works fine on visual studio community 2019 but is not working in visual studio.

Here a screenshot of the error I'm facing.

[image]

```
#include <filesystem>
int main(){
std::cout << "hello world" << endl; 
}
```

just including filesystem lib and compiling the same throws me the error below,

```
    > Executing task: g++ -g -Wall --std=c++17 main.cpp -o main.exe <

In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\filesystem:37,
                 from main.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h: In member function 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path& std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::operator/=(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:221:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _StateT> bool std::operator!=(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)'     
     operator!=(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:221:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\filesystem:37,
                 from main.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::fpos<_StateT>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:456:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)'
     operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:456:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\filesystem:37,
```

Comment: A screenshot won't do. You must copy the *text* into the question. No one can google for the error that is in a picture.

Comment: sorry. i have added a link check that. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbHo3.png

Comment: @hitbox *Edit* the question. Post the text of the error. A link in a comment is *not* good enough.

Comment: You should always post errors as text. I don't want to type the relevant part of the error message manually do a search.

Comment: really sorry new to stackoverflow. let me add the error into the post

Comment: @JesperJuhl have added the error in text

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ThomasSablik hi. yes added a minimal code snippet.

Comment: Your code snippet can't be compiled because `std::cout` and `endl` are not declared: https://wandbox.org/permlink/LXKGjhFzvssKrRhd `note: 'std::cout' is defined in header '<iostream>'; did you forget to '#include <iostream>'?` What compilers do you use?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc [...]

[`<filesystem>` is known to not compile on GCC by MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619049/compilation-errors-for-c17-filesystem-on-mingw).

Your error message states that, despite you claiming to use Microsoft Visual Studio, you are compiling with different compiler (MSVS uses its own compiler) - GCC for Windows (from MinGW).

I suggest you sticking with the original compiler from Microsoft Visual Studio.