# Why do I get error when I use #include<bits/stdc++.h> in Clion IDE?

Tags: c++, header-files, clion

In file included from

```
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/filesystem:37,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/stdc++.h:127,
                 from C:\Users\Naafiz\CLionProjects\cute-project\main.cpp:1:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h: In member function 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path& std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::operator/=(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
```

Comment: Don't *ever* include that header. It's an implementation *detail* of a specific implementation. Not portable between implementations/compilers. *Not* intended to *ever* be included by user code. It may change at any time without warning, you *cannot* rely on it. Whatever taught you to include that header is a resource you should *stop* reading *right now*.

Comment: Not to mention that it includes *everything* which makes build-times of simple source files grow by many magnitudes. Only include the header you actually need.

Comment: Also note that `std::filesystem` doesn't really work in mingw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619049/compilation-errors-for-c17-filesystem-on-mingw